# MATLAB Find the max point from a dsolve formula

Tags: matlab, max, differential-equations

I'm solving two differential equations and plotting the results of the second differential equation. I want to find the values at the max point in the plot. However, maybe because I'm using `sym`, I'm having trouble figuring how to do it. I know that in math, you would just find the first derivative and set it to zero.

```
% Constants
k1 = 1/10; 
k2 = 1/1.3; 
k3 = 1/1.3; 
k4 = 1/(1/48);
k5 = 1/3.9; 
t = 1:5;
% Initial concentration
A0 = 5891.694;
B0 = 0; 
%%% Mass balance equation 1
syms A(t) t
eqn = diff(A,t) == -k1*A -k2*A -k3*A -k4*A;
cond = A(0) == A0;
A(t) = dsolve(eqn,cond);
% A(t) = exp(-k1*t);
%%% Mass balance equation 2
syms B(t) t
eqn = diff(B,t) == k1*A +k2*A +k3*A +k4*A - k5*B;
cond = B(0) == B0;
B(t) = dsolve(eqn,cond); 

%%% Plot
figure('visible','on');
t = 0:20;
plot(t,B(t))
```

[image: plot of B(t)]

So for the picture above, I'd like to find the max point. Sometimes, it isn't at exact time steps so I want MATLAB to just show the exact values at the max point.

Comment: You should increase the resolution of your plot. 20 sample points is not very informative. Set `t = 0:0.05:20` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findpeaks` to find maxima in your data. To do so, first you need to convert your ode solution (algebraic expression) into a data list for a specific interval of study.

```
B(t) = dsolve(eqn,cond,'t') ;
t = 0:0.1:20;
z=eval(B(t))
```

Now using `findpeaks`

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(z)
```

> pks =
>
> 5.7310e+03
>
> locs =
>
> ```
>  2
> ```